# Missing printer filters

Tags: printing

I am using ubuntu 20.04 and am trying to install a brother printer via usb connection. But I get the error message:

"There is a missing print filter for printer 'MFC-J5910DW'

And the `/var/log/cups/error_log` contains the following information:

```
MFC-J5910DW: File \"/usr/lib/cups/filter/brother_lpdwrapper_mfcj5910dw\" not available: No such file or directory
```

I guess this missing file is the problem, but I don't know how what I need to do to solve it-so I'd appreciate any help.
Best, Barbara

Comment: Did you get it?

Answer (score 1):

With Linux, don’t expect to run a driver setup wizard. Brother is actually known for supporting Linux and do release its own printer drivers. Before you start this process, visit Brother’s website to see if they have support info for **your model**. While at the company site, look for *.deb* or a *PPD* file that you can use to manually provide the optimal driver for your printer.

Just google your model number (in your case 'Brother MFC-J5910DW') then download the Linux/.deb utility and printer drivers, whatever they have. May I emphasize reading any help they have there too. **BTW**, since you are there, download the manuals, etc.

*Install then sit back and watch the fireworks fly.* ;))

Comment: I did exactly that. Brother has a deb-Linux driver for my printer, and I downloaded the two archives that they provided. I then looked into those archives and found the .ppd file. The printer gets automatically detected, only that it doesn't respond. So I went into CUPS, and used the option: 'modify printer'. In this process you get the option to selsct your own .ppd file. So I entered the one that I downloaded from Brother. It all seems to work fine,, but when I want to pritn a test page, it just doesn't work. CUPS  just shows under 'jobs':

Comment: ID: MFC-J5910DW-11 , NAME: unknown, USER: withheld, SIZE: 1k, PAGES: unknown, STATE: stopped. So where did I go wrong?

Comment: Did you install the .deb file? I thought the 'Driver Install Tool' could have saved you the trouble of installing them for you.

Comment: I just focused on the .ppd file, extracted that and used it. But that's probably not what you meant with 'installing the .deb file'. So what exactly did you mean?

Comment: I didn't know that you can use apt-get to install .deb files directly, but I found out that you can and I did that. But I still get an error message:

Comment: `$ sudo apt-get install ./mfcj5910dwcupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb  \\
Reading package lists... Done \\
Building dependency tree   \\     
Reading state information... Done   \\
Note, selecting 'mfcj5910dwcupswrapper:i386' instead of './mfcj5910dwcupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb' \\
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.` \\

Comment: `The following information may help to resolve the situation: \\  
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mfcj5910dwcupswrapper:i386 : Depends: mfcj5910dwlpr:i386 but it is not installable \\  
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did to make it work:

1. I went to https://www.brother.de/support/mfc-j5910dw/downloads
2. I downloaded two printer driver packages for the MFC-J5910DW printer:

   - LPR printer driver (deb package)
   - CUPSwrapper printer driver (deb package)
3. I opened a terminal and went into the directory into which I had downloaded the two packages.
4. I installed both packages using apt:

   ```
   sudo apt install ./mfcj5910dwlpr-3.0.0-1.i386.deb ./mfcj5910dwcupswrapper-3.0.0-1.i386.deb
   ```
5. I went into CUPS (http://localhost:631/admin) and printed a test page, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

1. Switch on the printer
2. Goto Ubuntu Settings -> Printer and Add a New Printer
3. Select enter URI and enter: ipp://localhost:60000/ipp/print
4. Choose driver -> Provide PPD -> enter the full path to your PPD file
5. Proceed from there...